# SQS and Lambda: Limit max. amount of processed messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

If using SQS as an event source for a Lambda function, is there a way to limit the maximum amount of "active" messages to x. So, imagine there's a SQS queue with 1000 messages but instead of trying to process as many messages as possible (up to the default concurrency limit of 1000) we only want to process up to x messages at the same time. This obviously means that it'll take more time to process all messages but it would give us a possibility to better control e.g. writes to a database.

Also, in case a message can't be processed (due to e.g. an error that occurred in the Lambda function), is the message appended to the end of the queue (so all other messages are coming first) or is there a way to prioritise them after a certain waiting time (visibility timeout)?

Many thanks

Comment: sounds like batch processing, w/ a VSEM input or something of that sort. Trigger off of a queue is tough for this because downstream processes/apps likely cant scale to the power of AWS lambda concurrency. I have experienced this, and we used a cloudwatch cron to trigger a lambda worker and would set a predefined amount of messages it would fetch.

Comment: @LostJon Thanks, I'll have a look at Cloudwatch cron and how that could potentially work. I also read somewhere that Kinesis Data Streams might be able to do something like this (instead of SQS queues) but also not sure yet.

Answer (score 2):

As for throttling a queue, you could of added a Delivery Delay time or make it long polling but as yours is event driven this isn't a choice. So this leaves you with throttling your lambda to x many you want done a concurrently.

As for the messages which cant be processed that depends whether you are using 
- standard queue, which wont hold any prioritization which message is picked up next. 
- a .fifo queue Which will try to process it again as it would be next in line chronologically.

But if you caught the error you should send it straight to a dead letter queue to prevent unnecessary retries.

Although by throttling it you're removing all scalability of AWS, which is against its native architecture. Id recommend going back to the Database and seeing if any work can be improved there instead to avoid throttling.

Comment: The problem is that we don't just have one queue but many different queues with lots of messages. At some point sooner or later we hit some limit. Don't get me wrong, scalability is great but we want to limit the scale out to a certain extend (it should scale to x concurrent lambdas if needed).

Throttling Lambdas in combination with SQS seems to have some issues unfortuntaly but would otherwise be a good solution. 

Putting errors back into a different queue seems to be a possible soltion. We just want to avoid that errored messages are put back to the "end" of the queue...

Answer (score 1):

From [Reserving Concurrency for a Lambda Function - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/per-function-concurrency.html):

> You can configure a function with reserved concurrency to guarantee that it can always reach a certain level of concurrency. Reserving concurrency also limits the maximum concurrency for the function.
>
> ...
>
> **Your function can't scale out of control** – Reserved concurrency also limits your function from using concurrency from the unreserved pool, capping it's maximum concurrency. Reserve concurrency to prevent your function from using all the available concurrency in the region, or from overloading downstream resources.

If a message is not processed within the invisibility timeout period, it is placed back on the queue. There is no guarantee of ordering of messages in Amazon SQS unless you are using a FIFO queue, which has further limitations on in-flight messages.

Comment: Thanks, the issue with lambda concurrency is that it apparently doesn't play well with SQS as per e.g. this or similar posts: https://medium.com/@zaccharles/lambda-concurrency-limits-and-sqs-triggers-dont-mix-well-sometimes-eb23d90122e0

But I'd assume there's no ideal solution to this problem then.

Regaring the ordering: So, when an error is occured the mesaage is added to the "end" of the queue (no guaratee of ordering but it will be processed after all the other messages which were added in the meantime)?

Comment: It is best to think of the queue as providing no guaranteed ordering _at all_. There is no such concept as the 'start' or 'end' of a non-FIFO queue. In general, you are likely to see a FIFO-ish behaviour, but you should not rely on that always being the case. You could experiment to see whether failed messages go towards the back-ish or front-ish of the queue.

Comment: That article is interesting! Such behaviour would certainly impact the ability to use concurrency to limit Lambda consuming SQS messages.